# Why, decimal integer constants are signed and hexadecimal counterparts can be both signed and unsigned, even though they refer to same set of values?

Tags: c, types

I'm reading Modern C, by Jens Gustedt and author points out the following,

- All value have a type that is statically determined.

-At the starting of the chapter author said " C programs primarily reason about values and not about their representation ". So are literals, say decimal integer constant ways to represent a value or they have an intrinsic value.

- Also stated was " We don't want result of computation to depend on executable which is platform specific but ideally depend only on program specification itself. An IMPORTANT STEP TO ACHIEVE THIS PLATFORM INDEPENDENCE IS THE CONCEPT OF TYPES ".
  What does the text in uppercase actually mean, how do types help in platform independence. What is the use of types?
- Why, decimal integer constants are signed and hexadecimal counterparts can be both signed and unsigned, even though they refer to same set of values?

I'm really confused at this point. If someone could answer each point and elaborate, I'll be grateful.

Comment: There is  a nice [table](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1p5) in the C standard, that would remove any confusion. Yes, it does not explain "why". But why not?

Answer (score 4):

> Why, decimal integer constants are signed and hexadecimal counterparts can be both signed and unsigned, even though they refer to same set of values?

This appears to allude to C 2018 6.4.4.1 5, which specifies the type of an integer constant. For a decimal constant with no suffix, the candidate types are all signed: `int`, `long int`, and `long long int`. (The choice from among these depends on the value of the constant.) For a hexadecimal constant with no suffix, the candidate types are a mix of signed and unsigned: `int`, `unsigned int`, `long int`, `unsigned long int`, `long long int`, and `unsigned long long int`.

This specification of candidate lists is not based on the values that each can represent, since, as you point out, decimal and hexadecimal notations can both represent any integer value. It is simply based on common use. Use of decimal constants fell largely into use with signed types (e.g., decimal constants were often used when doing general arithmetic) and use of hexadecimal constants was more diverse (e.g., hexadecimal constants were often used when working with bits), and presumably the C committee felt these rules suited the existing usage.

Answer (score 3):

> Why, decimal integer constants are signed and hexadecimal counterparts can be both signed and unsigned, even though they refer to same set of values?

You are kind of misunderstanding this part. It's really about the **type** of the constant. It's not about the signedness.

So assuming 32 bit int (2's complement) the following apply:

```
0x7ffffff has type int
0x8000000 has type unsigned int
```

The reason is that 0x80000000 is greater than INT_MAX and therefore can't be an int.

This is important because of the way usual arithmetic
conversions work. In case of 0x7fffffff the conversion will be towards int while in case of 0x80000000 the conversion will be towards unsigned int.

To put it in other word:

0x.... is always a value greater or equal to zero. If it's value fits into the range of `int`, its type will be an `int`. If it can't fit into `int` the the next step is to see if it fits into `unsigned int` in which case its type will be `unsigned int` and so on for `long int, unsigned long int, long long int, unsigned long long int`

An example (32 bit 2's complement):

The binary representation 0x80000000 as **`int`** represents the value -2147483648.

The binary representation 0x7fffffff as **`int`** represents the value 2147483647.

So from this it must be true that `0x7fffffff > 0x80000000` is true. Right?

Try:

```
int main(void) 
{
    if (0x7fffffff > 0x80000000)
    {
        puts("0x7fffffff is bigger than 0x80000000");
    }
    else
    {
        puts("0x7fffffff is less than 0x80000000");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So this "should" print: `0x7fffffff is bigger than 0x80000000` Right?

**No, it won't**. It prints `0x7fffffff is less than 0x80000000`. The reason is (again) that 0x80000000 is considered unsigned int so the comparison is done on unsigned types. This shows why the type of integer constants can be important.

Finally try:

```
int main(void) 
{
    if (((0x7fffffff - 0x40000000) - 0x40000000) > 0)
    {
        puts("(0x7fffffff - 0x40000000) - 0x40000000) is bigger than zero");
    }
    else
    {
        puts("(0x7fffffff - 0x40000000) - 0x40000000) is less than zero");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
(0x7fffffff - 0x40000000) - 0x40000000) is less than zero
```

This shows that the expression `(0x7fffffff - 0x40000000) - 0x40000000)` was calculated as `int` (i.e. had any operand been unsigned, result could not be less than zero).

Comment: The type (`int` or `unsigned int`) is not stored in the bits.  The number is interpreted based on what the programmer has designated the type to be.

Comment: `2.0` is a *display representation,* not a storage representation.  I don't think you're right about this.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's just like decimal representation for `int` - no different. 102 is not a binary representation but it's still a representation of an integer constant of type `int`

Comment: OK, so you're saying that `0x7ffffff` is a *display representation* that is interpreted as a signed integer?

Comment: And `0x8000000` is a *display representation* that is interpreted as an unsigned integer?

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes, 0x7fffffff is a hexadecimal representation of a `int` (assuming 32 bits and 2's compliment of cause)

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes, 0x80000000 has type unsigned int

Comment: @RobertHarvey What decimal value do you expect 0x80000000 to be? Minus some big number? Or a positive big number?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Take a look: https://godbolt.org/z/dern7rqjr (or https://ideone.com/X76YDp)

Comment: @RobertHarvey See https://ideone.com/ISa4qY

Comment: This answer does not speak to the issue being asked about (which unfortunately was not stated clearly in the question): When there is no `u` suffix, the candidate types for decimal constants are all signed (`int`, `long int`, `long long int`), but the candidate types for hexadecimal constants are both signed and unsigned (`int`, `unsigned int`, `long int`, `unsigned long int`, `long long int`, and `unsigned long long int`).

Comment: @EricPostpischil hmm... well, I think that's exactly what it does... there is no u suffix in the example which is why the type of a hexadecimal integer constant can be both `int` and `unsigned int` (obviously 0x7fffffffU is always unsigned). That's exactly what I tried to describe. Feel free to improve the wording.

Comment: @matt The type is how the compiler is treating this specific value when performing different operations on it. It is "stored" in the compiler "database" at the compilation time.

Comment: @matt Not sure where this phrase is coming from, as it does not appear in the answer. Same bit pattern can represent values of different types, so it is most definitely incorrect. Type is mostly a compile-time construct.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Exactly, It isn't in the answer but the first comment asks about it and 4386427 replies with "Yes, the type is stored in the bits when using integer constants" which doesn't makes sense to me.

Comment: @matt: A bit of confusion on everyone's part, but no, it's not stored in the bits.  `0x7ffffff` is a *display representation;* it doesn't store anything.  Rather, it is *source code that is compiled.* That representation is treated differently by the C compiler than `0x8000000`, for similar reasons that `2.0` is treated differently by the compiler than `2`.